# Como aplicar a mudança na cor do placeholder apenas em alguns text-box

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como mudar a cor do placeholder de inputs específicos. Exemplo:

```css
input{
display:block;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:200px;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder = "Esse na cor que eu desejar">

<input type="text" placeholder = "Esse na cor padrão">
```

Porque estou perguntando ? Porque eu tenho uma página onde eu estilizo o placeholder como no código CSS do exemplo, porém os meus formulários de registro/perfil também recebem esse estilo.Exemplo:

Nessa parte gostaria que o placeholder fosse mais escuro.
[image: Quero que estilize]

E nessa que ele fosse normal.
[image: Placeholder normal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa definir uma classe para o `placeholder` que você deseja alterar.

### Seletor classe

Você pode "inventar" um nome e definí-lo como valor a ser atribuido ao atributo class (classe) do elemento HTML. O nome "inventado" será o seletor para aplicar declarações CSS. E o mais interessante das classes, é que elas podem ser aplicadas a qualquer elemento HTML. E mais ainda, você pode aplicar estilos diferentes para o mesmo tipo de elemento da HTML, usando classes diferentes para cada um deles.

**É isso que você precisa!**

***Veja no exemplo abaixo:***

Note que eu defini que o `placeholder` com a cor vermelha vai ser atribuído somente em elementos que conterem a classe `cor-vermelha`.

No elemento html eu atribui a classe `cor-vermelha` a ele através do seguinte código: `class="cor-vermelha"`

NOTA: Para o nome que você "inventa" evite usar números e caracteres especiais. Tanto quanto possível use só letras de a-z e de A-Z. Há restrições quanto ao uso de números e caracteres. Minha experiência e conselho: use somente letras e os caracteres - (traço) e _ (sublinhado).

```css
input{
display:block;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:200px;
}


.cor-vermelha::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: red;
}

.cor-vermelha:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.cor-vermelha::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.cor-vermelha:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
}

.cor-vermelha::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="cor-vermelha" placeholder = "Esse na cor que eu desejar">

<input type="text" placeholder = "Esse na cor padrão">
```

Referência: [Site Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `class=`, assim:

```css
input{
display:block;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:200px;
}


.especifico::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: red;
}

.especifico:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.especifico::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
}

.especifico:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
}

.especifico::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="especifico" type="text" placeholder = "Esse na cor que eu desejar">

<input type="text" placeholder = "Esse na cor padrão">
```